# Unable to retrieve values from CSR using Phpseclib

Tags: phpseclib

Following the example from the link I am able to parse a CSR fine. However if I try to retrieve individual attributes i get errors.. Its strange though using the same method I can pull info from a public key but just not the CSR..

Phpseclib CSR parser:
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/examples.html#readcsr

This works:

`Print_r($csr);`

This does not work??

`$CN = $csr['certificationRequestInfo']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value']['utf8String'];
echo $CN;`

Comment: It works for me using the sample CSR provided at the link you posted. Maybe you're testing on a different CSR that has some other type of string other than utf8String? What happens when you do `$csr['certificationRequestInfo']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value']`?

Comment: Thx neubert, issue was due to me trying to parse a microsoft CSR. Apache CSRs are a non issue. You had resolved this on another thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662336/phpseclib-cant-parse-csr-from-microsoft-ca) - you seem to be the phpseclib expert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved and was due to lack of support for parsing Microsoft CSR's.. The fix can be found here [phpseclib cant parse CSR from Microsoft CA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662336/phpseclib-cant-parse-csr-from-microsoft-ca)